# TableView in iOS 5 Crashed with ARC enabled

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I have this problem with a tableview in iOS5 that is giving me errors, note that it works well with the older sdk. 
This is the relevant code:
h file
    #import

```
@interface WordListTableViewController : UITableViewController {
  //NSMutableDictionary *words;
  //NSArray *sections;
}
@end
```

m file
     #import "WordListTableViewController.h"
     #import "DefinitionViewController.h"

```
@interface WordListTableViewController()
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *words;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *sections;
@end


@implementation WordListTableViewController

@synthesize  words, sections;
- (NSMutableDictionary *) words
{
   if(!words){
          NSURL *wordsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/Vocabulous.txt"];
          words = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:wordsURL] ;
   }
   return words;
}

- (NSArray *) sections
{
    if(!sections)
    {
       sections = [[self.words allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] ;
    }
    return sections;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"WordListTableViewCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
//cell.textLabel.text = cell.textLabel.text = [self wordAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";


    return cell;
}
```

h File for App Delegate 
    #import

```
@interface VocabAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic)  UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *nav;
@end
```

m File for App Delegate with relevant code : 
    #import "VocabAppDelegate.h"
    #import "WordListTableViewController.h"

```
@implementation VocabAppDelegate
@synthesize window;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    WordListTableViewController *wltvc = [[WordListTableViewController alloc] init];
    self.nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: wltvc ];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

The Error is the following: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS
It's like it only sets the visible cells and when I start scrolling down looking for the not visible ones, it's like they can't be displayed.

Fina UPDATE :
Following the advise from mattyhoe, I've replaced the method wordAtIndexPath with a static text, and followed the other two side notes Plus the way I use the delegate and it works !!!

Thanks

Comment: You're doing a couple things wrong there. First, the `addSubview:` bit is really an old way of doing things, and unless you're supporting applications prior to 4.0 (which you can't with ARC enabled) then you want to actually set the `rootViewController` property on `UIWindow`. I would recommend creating a `@property` for your navigation controller as well in your app delegate, and alloc it with `initWithRootViewController:`. So: `self.nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: [[WordListTableViewController alloc] init]];` Then proceed to add the nav as the window's RVC.

Comment: For examples of how to do this, make a new project and choose Master-Detail Application. Look in the app delegate to see how to properly setup your view controllers.

Comment: Post the stack trace from your crash and any other messages logged leading up to the crash.

Comment: @robmayoff From the *View Programming Guide for iOS*: "To install a view in your window, use the addSubview: method....In place of the preceding code, you can alternatively configure the rootViewController property of the window in your nib file."

Comment: Well, I have to say that in Practice for iOS5 and ARC enabled, it didn't work. rootViewController is that way to go as mayttyhoe said, my code has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing looks out of place there, so it's likely the work you're doing inside of wordAtIndexPath. To test this theory, simply replace that line with something like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";
```

As a side note, you do not need to declare ivars. Simply use `@property`s.
Also, you likely want to set the accessory type when you're allocing a new cell and not every time this method is called, so moving it inside the conditional makes sense.

Comment: How are you allocating WordListTableViewController?

Comment: Thanks for the help, mattyohe, I've followed your advice and posted an update of the code, however, I still have the same problem.